# Haskell: laziness affected by parsing method

Tags: parsing, haskell, input, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I have a simple program (it was the second question on [CCC 2012](http://cemc.math.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing.html)) that takes a list of numbers and determines if there is any strictly increasing/decreasing/constant sequence going on. For example:

```
1 2 3 4 7 8 => Increasing
5 1 -2 -100 => Decreasing
9 9 9 9 9 9 => Constant
1 2 3 4 5 0 => Nothing
```

I was completely blown away by how smart Haskell was when I coded this. For some reason, when I typed in the numbers interactively into stdin, in was giving me the answer before I had even finished! I thought it was a bug, but then I foolishly realized that Haskell's laziness (I think?) was taking it upon itself to decide that, after I entered `1`, `2`, `3`, `0`, no matter what came after, the result would be `Nothing`, and so it happily outputted that.

Unfortunately, when I changed

```
let readings = map (read :: (Read a, Num a) => String -> a) $ lines input
```

to

```
let readings = parse $ lines input
```

with `parse` being a safer method of reading numerical input, implemented as

```
maybeRead :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . filter (null . dropWhile isSpace . snd) . reads

parse :: (Read a) => [String] -> [a]
parse xs =
    let entries = map maybeRead xs
    in if all isJust entries
        then map fromJust entries
        else []
```

it no longer does this.

Why?

EDIT: More code

```
-- | Zip together adjacent list elements as pairs in a new list.
zipPairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
zipPairs xs = zip (init xs) (tail xs)

-- | Return True if all elements of a given list are equal.
constant :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
constant xs = all (== head xs) (tail xs)

-- | Return the order that the elements of a list are sorted in, if they form
-- a strictly increasing (Just LT), decreasing (Just GT) or constant (Just EQ)
-- sequence. If there is no pattern, return Nothing.
order :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe Ordering
order xs =
    let orders = map (\(x, y) -> x `compare` y) (zipPairs xs)
    in if constant orders then Just (head orders) else Nothing
```

and then in `main`I have

```
let readings = parse $ lines input
putStrLn $ if null readings
    then "bad input"
    else case order readings of
        Just EQ -> "Constant"
        Just LT -> "Diving"
        Just GT -> "Rising"
        Nothing -> "Nothing"
```

Comment: +1 for the revelation of the epiphany ;) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all entries are justs, `all isJust entries` checks the entire list of entries, which means that the entire list of entries needs to be read in before `parse` can return.

Okay, longer explanation of why `orders` is lazy -- `all` returns `False` as soon as it reaches a value for which the predicate returns `False`.  Therefore, `constant` returns false as soon as it hits a value in the tail that isn't equal to the head.  `order` returns as soon as `constant` returns, so `order` is lazy.

My first suggestion is stylistic -- look at the `zipWith` function when calculating `orders`.  `let orders = zipWith compare xs $ tail xs` should work equally well.

As far as solving your actual problem is concerned, try

```
order xs = let orders = zipWith (liftM2 compare) xs $ tail xs
           in if isJust (head orders) && constant orders
              then head orders
              else Nothing
```

Note that you need to import `Data.Monad`

`liftM2 compare` will return `Just (compare x y)` when passed `Just x` and `Just y` and `Nothing` if either or both of its arguments are `Nothing`.

`orders` is now a `[Maybe Ordering]`.  If `orders` is constant (note: `(==)` works on `Maybe`s) and the first element is a `Just`, return the first element (which is already a `Maybe Ordering`).  Otherwise, just return `Nothing`.  You could do without the `isJust (head orders)` call, but adding it should make it return as soon as it sees a `Nothing` (otherwise, if you give it a list of all `Nothing`s, it will check if every one is `Nothing`).

Comment: I was going to do that before, but the problem is that will allow bad input to go silently unnoticed. If I enter `1`, `2`, `efyugf` and `3`, that whole thing should get thrown away, not interpreted as 1-2-3.

Comment: You are correct that it exhibits the same behaviour as before when I make this change. Is there no way of doing what I want while avoiding the above?

Comment: The problem is what happens if you enter in `1`, `2`, `1`, `efuas`?  `parse` can't return anything because it might need to return `[]`.  If it returns `1:2:1:rest of list` and then hits `efuas`, it would have to "unreturn" the initial part of the list, which doesn't even make sense.  Because of this, `parse` has to wait until the entire list is read in before returning anything.  The only solution I can see is to move everything into the same function or relax the error checking constraints.

Comment: I see what you mean now… It's like if I inputted a file, it wouldn't know for sure whether the rest of the file is valid until it scanned the whole thing. I guess what I want is for it to stop if it reaches a bad input, but not care if it hasn't seen any so far and can safely output the answer now. The problem is I don't really understand how it knows that it's able to finish early, so I don't know how that would be implemented.

Comment: Just saw your edit—is what your suggesting what I just described? By returning nothing, do you mean `[Nothing]`?

Comment: Whatever you are doing to output "Nothing" when you see something like "1 2 1" -- without seeing your code, I can't say exactly what it is.  I am assuming that you have a function somewhere that takes a list of numbers and returns/outputs Increasing/Decreasing/Constant/Nothing (no clue what the data types are there).  This function needs to handle maybes.  If you posted the code to this function, I could provide more specific help.

Comment: Yes, I have a function which takes a (plain, not Maybe) list and returns a `Maybe Ordering` (in this case the Maybe is only to there to allow for the 4th type, Nothing). I've edited the question and added the relevant code.

Comment: If you are willing to have `1 2 3 efuas` output `Increasing`, you can do something like `takeWhile isJust` to take the initial however many valid numbers and stop when you hit an invalid input, as an alternate suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was I was thinking of! Thank you.

Comment: Actually… I just realized that the `takeWhile` solution is just like the filter one, except that `1 2 3 efuas 3` => `1 2 3 3` => Nothing with filter, while => `1 2 3` => Increasing with `takeWhile`, which actually isn't that much better.

Comment: So maybe I would be interested in handling Maybes with my other function if it wouldn't be that hard to describe

Comment: I think it would just make the code more complicated than it needs to be, so I think I'll just leave it as it is, without the cool laziness, but thanks for helping me understand everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `mapMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`. That is, swap `map read` with `mapMaybe maybeRead`. What `mapMaybe` does is map the function over the list, filter out the `Nothing`s and extract all the remaining values.

Comment: You're right, that's like what Retief suggested, only cleaner than doing my own `map` and `filter isJust`. But it's still not ideal.

Comment: Its a good suggestion -- much better than my `map fromJust $ filter isJust $ map f` or list comprehension stylistically.